# Handle Error without Redirect & Page Refresh in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

How can I handle errors without redirecting or refreshing page in MVC?

In fact, my View.cshtml has several  tags and I want to post a specific  and handle errors (if any) without redirecting and refreshing the page. I actually want to alert the error.

The following is my JavaScript code snippet:

```
fn_GetData: function () {
    $('#frm4').attr('action', 'my url goes here').attr('method', 'post');
    $('#div4').html('<input type="hidden" name="p" value="' + 'some value goes here' + '"/> ');
    $('#frm4').submit();
}
```

Here is my Controller Action code:

```
public ActionResult GetData(string p)
{
    var error = false;
    // Some logic goes here...
    if (error)
    {
        TempData["Result"] = "My error message goes here";
        // I don't know how to alert the above error message without having to redirect or refresh the page.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller methodds can return various types of content.

For example you can use

```
return Json()
```

and give an object to the method. This will turn your object into Json that you can then handle in your JS code.
Even simpler, you can return just a string and handle that in your JS, if you really only need the error message.

The page should not reload, if you use either of these methods for the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve that with a "submit" of a form. POSTing a form will trigger page reload from the browser.
What your a looking for is an AJAX call to a web service that will return a validation result.

Look at jQuery ajax method if you are using jQuery on your client side. You can that way call your controller action and do whatever rendering in your page in javascript.